# External SD card keeps unmounting

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, external-sd, samsung-galaxy-s-5

Everytime my sd card unmount itself automatically and mount again and sometime... it won't mount. Restarting and/or shutting down the phone won't do anything.

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S5 with android 4.4.2.

Help someone.

Answer (score 1):

You have to format the SD card.

Comment: Please don't use comments for extended discussion -- feel free to use [chat] for that.  And do incorporate any concrete solution into this answer post!